# Updating last entry of selected list

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I'm trying to update table where is no unique keys, for that reason I need find last entry of group and update it. I'm adding code to understand logic, because I don't know how should I write it in Postgres

```
UPDATE table 
SET column_name = 'VALUE'
WHERE (SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE group = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your (group, date) seem to be primary key though.

You can use `WITH` query:

```
WITH _cte AS (
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE group = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 )
UPDATE table
SET column_name = 'VALUE'
FROM _cte
WHERE _cte.group = table.group AND _cte.date = table.date;
```

btw: It helps to avoid sql keywords as table/column names.